# c++ visual studio 64bit | save registers value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, masm

I am using detour to hook some function, this function saves some variables in the registers, in order to hook to the function and return to the real code after the hook (and in order that it will work) I need to save the value in those registers and load them after. With 32 bit version I just ran this code:

```
DWORD esireg = 0;
DWORD eaxreg = 0;
__asm
{
    mov esireg, esi
    mov eaxreg, eax
}
```

now my code runs and after  I have finished I load the registers.

```
__asm
{
    mov esi, esireg
    mov eax, eaxreg
}
```

my problem is that in 64bit in visual there is no inline assembly after searching a bit in google, any one have any ideas how I can save the registers value and after that writing to there?

I tried to create an external asm file like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZCkYr1FB8

the problem is I need to save the registers value to a variable so when I try to write:

```
savereg proc
    mov esireg, esi
savereg endp
```

it says: "undefined symbol esireg"

any ideas guys?

Comment: Why not push them on the stack if you want to save/restore across a function call?  That's usually better than static storage, and has the advantage of being re-entrant + thread-safe.  Also, RSI is call-preserved in the Windows x64 calling convention so you don't actually need to save it unless you want to use it yourself, though.

Answer (score 1):

You've already discovered that you need a separate source for the assembly code. If you want to save the registers, you can save them in global variables declared in either the assembly source file or the C++ source file. If the variables are declared in the C++ source file, then they will need to public in the C++ file and declared as "extrn" in the assembly source file. Example where the data is saved in the assembly file:

```
        .data
raxreg  dq      0
rsireg  dq      0

        .code
;       ...
        mov     raxreg,rax
        mov     rsireg,rsi
;       ...
        mov     rax,raxreg
        mov     rsi,rsireg
```

To include the assembly file in the build, you will need to define a custom build step. Right click on the assembly source file name, then properties. Turn off "excluded from build", then define the custom build step. For a debug build use:

```
command line: ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\examplea.obj examplea.asm
outputs:      $(OutDir)\examplea.obj
```

For a release build, the /Zi is not used:

```
command line: ml64 /c /Fo$(OutDir)\examplea.obj examplea.asm
outputs:      $(OutDir)\examplea.obj
```